# How to update the main form without creating another instance

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

I currently have two forms, which are the main form and the login form. 
My main form is my `Application.Run()`; and my login form is just a dialog box. 
I have already created a function for the reloading of data. My problem is *if i log out of my main form, then login again, the main form would not automatically refresh.*  I have placed my refresh function on the form_load event.  I tried creating a button for the refresh and its working just as I wanted it to.  How can I make my refresh function automatically change once I login another user?

This is on my program.cs:

```
   Application.Run(new Main_Form());
```

This is whats of inside my main form:

```
public partial class Main_Form : Form
{
    Login log = new Login();
}

private void Main_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    log.ShowDialog();
}
private void logoutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to logout?", "Logout", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        spms.classes.FormProvider.MainMenu.Hide();
        log.uname.Text = ("");
        log.pwd.Text = ("");
        log.ShowDialog();
        log.uname.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some code examples how your forms are now structured and how login form is called.

Comment: Do you close your login window after login and then the main form should reload?

Comment: If you hide and show your main form, then you can use OnShown() method.

Comment: @fedab yes.. my login form is just a dialog. after the dialog is closed the username would be passed on to the main form. i only need to find a way how would my main form updates its contents after the dialog is closed.

Comment: is there any possible event i could use?

Comment: @Sampath leme try that one..

Comment: The Shown event is only raised the first time a form is displayed; subsequently minimizing, maximizing, restoring, hiding, showing, or invalidating and repainting will not raise this event. i cant use this event.

Comment: i found the event. i use the Activated event and it seem to work fine. thanks for the comments and suggestions guys.

Answer (score 1):

When you close your login window:

```
YourDialog dialog = new YourDialog(...);

if(dialog.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK) //logged in successful
{
  ...
  YourRefreshButton_Click(...);
}
```

For your Dialog you have to set `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK` for the login button or your controls if you logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Play with the `.Visible` property:
`logoutToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;    //make it invisible`